# Bokeh 1.0.4 - selection across multiple glyphs with an interactive legend does not include all glyphs

Tags: selection, legend, bokeh

I am using interactive legends as in the example below

```
import pandas as pd

from bokeh.palettes import Spectral4
from bokeh.plotting import figure, output_file, show
from bokeh.sampledata.stocks import AAPL, IBM, MSFT, GOOG

p = figure(plot_width=800, plot_height=250,
           tools=('pan, lasso_select, reset'),
           active_drag='lasso_select',
           x_axis_type="datetime")
p.title.text = 'Click on legend entries to mute the corresponding lines'

for data, name, color in zip([AAPL, IBM, MSFT, GOOG], ["AAPL", "IBM", "MSFT", "GOOG"], Spectral4):
    df = pd.DataFrame(data)
    df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])
    p.circle(df['date'], df['close'], line_width=2, color=color, alpha=0.8,
             #selection_color='black',
             nonselection_color='gray',
             muted_color='gray', muted_alpha=0.2, legend=name)

p.legend.location = "top_left"
p.legend.click_policy="mute"

output_file("interactive_legend.html", title="interactive_legend.py example")

show(p)
```

If I make a selection like this with the lasso tool:
[image: while selecting with lasso]

after releasing the mouse I see:

[image: after selecting]

Notice that the points for MSFT and GOOG remain selected even though none of them were inside the selection region.

I would like them to become unselected (gray) in this case.

Apparently if none of the points in a glyph are inside the selection region then all of the points of that glyph remain selected (i.e. the selection tool does not include all the glyphs in the figure).

Thank you for your help!

Comment: the orange and green points are not actually selected, they just don't change color to the gray color. If you were to use the 'selected' indices you would not get any data from MSFT and IBM, so it's only visual.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately this is the default behaviour of the `LassoSelectTool`. I can offer you, however, a nice work-around which will hide the glyphs if their points are not selected. Then you can use the ResetTool to show them back.  I hope it will work for you.

```
import pandas as pd
from bokeh.palettes import Spectral4
from bokeh.models import LassoSelectTool, ResetTool, CustomJS, LegendItem, Legend, ColumnDataSource
from bokeh.plotting import figure, output_file, show
from bokeh.sampledata.stocks import AAPL, IBM, MSFT, GOOG

p = figure(plot_width = 800, plot_height = 250,
           tools = ('pan,reset'),
           x_axis_type = "datetime")
p.title.text = 'Click on legend entries to mute the corresponding lines'

sources = []
backup_colors = []
stocks = ["AAPL", "IBM", "MSFT", "GOOG"]
for data, name, color in zip([AAPL, IBM, MSFT, GOOG], stocks, Spectral4):
    df = pd.DataFrame(data)
    df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])
    sources.append(ColumnDataSource(dict(x = df['date'], y = df['close'], color = len(df['close'].values) * [color])))
    backup_colors.append(len(df['close'].values) * [color])

renderers = []
for index, name in enumerate(['AAPL', 'IBM', 'MSFT', 'GOOG']):
    source = sources[index]
    renderers.append(p.circle(x = 'x',
                              y = 'y',
                              color = 'color',
                              source = source,
                              line_width = 2,
                              alpha = 0.8,
                              nonselection_color = 'gray',
                              muted_color = 'gray',
                              muted_alpha = 0.2,
                              legend = name))

legend_items = [LegendItem(label = stocks[index], renderers = [renderer], name = stocks[index]) for index, renderer in enumerate(renderers)]
legend = Legend(items = legend_items, name = 'stocks_legend')
p.add_layout(legend)
p.legend.click_policy = 'hide'

greys = len(backup_colors[0]) * ['#888888']
code = '''  selected_line = null;
            for (index in renderers){
                renderer = renderers[index];
                if (renderer.data_source.selected.indices.length > 0)
                {
                    selected_line = renderer.data_source.selected.indices.length
                    break;
                }
            }
            if (selected_line != null){
                for (index in renderers){
                    renderer = renderers[index];
                    if (renderer.data_source.selected.indices.length == 0){     
                        renderer.data_source.data['color'] = greys
                        renderer.data_source.change.emit();
                    }
                }
            }'''
lasso_select_tool = LassoSelectTool(select_every_mousemove = False)
lasso_select_tool.callback = CustomJS(args = dict(renderers = renderers, greys = greys), code = code)
p.add_tools(lasso_select_tool)

p.legend.location = "top_left"
p.legend.click_policy = "mute"

code = '''  for (index in renderers){
                renderer = renderers[index];
                renderer.data_source.data['color'] = colors[index];
                renderer.data_source.change.emit();
            } '''
p.js_on_event('reset', CustomJS(args = dict(renderers = renderers, colors = backup_colors), code = code))

show(p)
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Thank you for this Tony. Very helpful and I may use this but I would really rather that the untouched renderers stayed on the plot and became gray rather than being hidden.

Comment: In the meantime, I came up with a partial solution of my own: I added a on_change event to of the data sources when they are created and I have a flag (maintained in my own datamodel) which keeps track of whether they have been touched in the last selection event.  When a selection happens, the on_change() is called for the sources that were touched (red and blue in this example). Then I have a button that the user can press after they are done with the selection. The button calls a routine that redraws the graph with all of the untouched data sources rendered as gray (rather than hidden).

Comment: As I said, I very much like your solution as it does not require that I maintain these 'touched' flags and does not require rebuilding the graph which is obviously much slower than hiding, but your solution does not rendered the untouched data sources as gray which I would prefer. Is it possible to use your solution but cause the renderer to render all of the points as gray (i.e. use a different glyph than the one that was used when it was created)?  On a reset the correct (non-gray) glyph would need to be restored so that might be tricky.

Comment: Also, in my solution it is stupid to ask the user to click a button to fix up the selection. Ideally I would like to have this python method called in the LassoTool callback when the selection event is completed, but that is in JavaScript (server side). I was thinking of subclassing a Bokeh Data source and then passing the subclass to the JS callback, but I am not sure that will work.  The subclass could have the method to fix up the selection.
In short, the Bokeh selection model is not ideal. It should allow the concept of selections that extend across all the data sources in a graph.

Comment: See updated code. Now the unselected lines become grey